# Possible to do "conda build" from github branch?

Tags: git, conda-build

I know that I can tell conda to build from github as:

```
source:
  fn:  v1.6.0.tar.gz
  url: https://github.com/SciTools/iris/archive/v1.6.0.tar.gz
  md5: 24c2d55758325a8f05aadf99748c0d2a
```

or

```
source:
  git_url: git@github.com:SciTools/iris.git
  git_tag: v1.6.0
```

but how would one tell conda to build from a github branch?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just put the branch name in the `git_tag` section. All it does is `git checkout` that "tag", so it doesn't have to be an actual git tag. It can be anything that git can `checkout`.

For example, if you want to conda build from branch `udunits_xml_path`, use:

```
source:
  git_url: https://github.com/esc24/iris.git
  git_tag: udunits_xml_path
```