# Installing github version of package with Anaconda

Tags: python, git, sympy, anaconda

I have ***Sympy*** installed with *Anaconda*, my version (of Sympy) is 0.7.6 .

I want to be able to use the git version of Sympy. Do you know how can I tell to Anaconda to substitute the 2 versions ?

I've tried using the git clone command, but the Sympy folder from git and Anaconda doesn't look the same at all, so I can't replace one with another.

```
git clone git://github.com/sympy/sympy.git
```

> Is there a command like : "conda update-git sympy" ?

I found that answer, but I didn't understand how to do it.

[Possible to do "conda build" from github branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22546878/possible-to-do-conda-build-from-github-branch)

**UPDATE**: I've used the following command and it worked

```
python setup.py develop
```

in my sympy directory.

Thanks to @asmeurer

Comment: basically what you did is to install the sympy build for development, and than you copied the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my previous answer was based on long time ago experiance
this is the correct proccess (that worked for me based on the latest anaconda on a windows machine)

I have updated the meta.yaml only with the following changes:
changing to get the source from git
including mpmath in build run and test
removing some libraries of sympy that seemed to have been removed from the latest version

i have all the files in the following gist
https://gist.github.com/srgrn/622cf61b03b7321503cc

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following:

1. download the conda recipes (https://github.com/conda/conda-recipes)
2. update the meta.yaml for getting the source from github as explained in the stack overflow question you linked to.
3. run conda build.

Comment: I've tried but I got an error
`Processing dependencies for sympy==0.7.7.dev0
Searching for mpmath>=0.19
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 352, in <module>
    install_requires=['mpmath>=%s' % mpmath_version]
......
RuntimeError: Setuptools downloading is disabled in conda build. Be sure to add all dependencies in the meta.yaml  url=https://pypi.python.org/simple/mpmath/r
Command failed: /bin/bash -x -e /Users/Nouveau/Projets/conda/sympy/build.sh`
Seems strange because
`conda update mpmath
Fetching package metadata: ....
# All requested packages already installed.`

Comment: i can't find this branch where did you took it from?
also you on windows or unix? seems like linux but i'm not sure with this path.

Comment: I'm on OSX, and I took this url from their Github repository https://github.com/sympy/sympy

Comment: i cloned it but i can't find this branch.

Comment: go into your sympy directory (git clone) and type the folowing command
`python setup.py develop`