# Git installing bleeding-edge version Theano on Windows

Tags: python, git, theano

I'm new to git but have to use git to install Theano.
See [this page](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install.html#bleeding-edge-install-instructions).

I've installed git on window using `msysgit`.
As I typed in `pip install --upgrade --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git` in Anaconda prompt, it got stuck at the cloning step.

```
(C:\Program Files\Anaconda2) C:\windows\system32>pip install --upgrade --no-deps
git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
Collecting git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
Cloning git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git to c:\users\liujy\appdata\local\temp\pip-k0i0se-build
```

I've checked the folder, there are files inside.

Can anybody give me some instruction on what to check next?

Comment: Please copy the text from the command line window and paste it into your question instead of posting screenshots of it.

Comment: @Atzmon. Thanks for helping editing. I can not paste a picture directly because my reputation is less than 10.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing github version of package with Anaconda](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30556900/installing-github-version-of-package-with-anaconda)